# How can I get the headers from the API response in flutter

Tags: api, flutter, dart

So if the response is {['myHeader': 'myData']}.

how can I get the 'myHeader'.

```
   FutureBuilder(
                          future: api_response,
    
                          builder: (context, snapshot){
                            return Text(snapshot.data[0]['myHeader']);
                          },
)
```

This is the code that I've been using to get the 'myData'.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please try testing below code.
You need to return Widget when snapshot has a data.

```
   FutureBuilder(
                          future: api_response,
    
                          builder: (context, snapshot){
                             if (snapshot.hasData) {
                                 return Text(snapshot.data[0]['myHeader']);
                             }
                          },
)
```

Comment: sorry I think you've misunderstood. I mean I want to get the header rather than the data. So if you look at my example, I want it to return 'myHeader'